# How to call overloaded method

Tags: python, class

I have the following structure:

```
# file1.py
class BaseExporter:

    def do_something(self):
        self._inner_call()

    def _inner_call(self):
        print 'do not execute this!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyExporter()
    x.do_something()

# file2.py
class MyExporter(BaseExporter):

    def _inner_call(self):
        print 'execute this!!!'
```

How do I get the `_do_something()` to call the `_inner_call` in my `MyExporter` class?

Comment: ...by doing exactly what you're already doing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe doesn't `self` refer to `BaseExporter` since it's invoked within that class?

Comment: 1. No; and 2. Why on earth didn't you just **run the example** rather than asking?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe or if the above correct, could you please clarify why that behavior is so?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's a 2hr script.

Comment: Your MCVE isn't, though. Why bother making it then not run it, even if just to make sure that it actually runs? I'd suggest you follow a basic OOP tutorial; unless you use `super`, the child implementation of a called method will be used even from parent methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should already work. MyExporter inherits the do_something method from the parent class and will call the subclass' inner_call method.